# Checking to see if email is in database after hitting submit then going to url php

Tags: php, database, forms, if-statement, submit

I'm setting up a RSVP type form on a wordpress page. Everything is sortof working but would like to fine tune things. Since I'm kindof new to PHP I thought I would ask some experts. I'm coming up with two problems.

1) When the page displays it starts checking for the email automatically before hitting submit. Is there a way to show nothing before hitting submit. Right now it is displaying the echo for the else.

2. When hitting submit the only way I was able to get the page to go to another url was through refresh. I couldn't get the header function to work it just kept going to a blank page.

I appreciate all the help. Here is my code.

```
 <?PHP 
    if($_POST['email'] != ''){
    // the email to validate  
    $email = $_POST['email']; 
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE rsvpemails='$email'"); 
}
if(mysql_num_rows($query) != 0) {
    echo '<div class="good"><h2>Your email is approved</h2>RSVP please <a href="url">continue to the RSVP form</a></div>';    
    echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=url">';    
    exit; 
}
else {
    echo '<div class="bad">Please enter your email address we used for the invite. If you have any questions or problems please email us at <a href="mailto:none@none.com">none@none.com</a></div> ';
}
?>
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="email">
<input type="button" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing to note is that your SQL query is vulnerable to SQL Injection.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

You should be sanitizing your POST variables, like ->

```
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
```

To your actual question, however -

1. Move your `if(mysql_num_rows($query) != 0)` block into the `if($_POST['email'] != '')` block so that it only checks for row data if $_POST['email'] is set (and consequently $query will be populated with something).
2. Here's also some more info on meta refresh tags.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I understand what you are saying to do I just don't know if I'm setting it up right. AGAIN THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR YOU HELP.
<?PHP
 if($_POST['email'] != '' && mysql_num_rows($query) != 0){
 $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE rsvpemails='$email'"); 
    echo 'message';    
    echo 'refresh';    
    exit; 
    }
  else {
    echo 'bad message';
    }
?>

Answer (score 0):

Put entire PHP code in condition.

```
<?php
if($_POST['email'] != ''){
    // the email to validate  
    $email = $_POST['email']; 
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE rsvpemails='$email'"); 

    if(mysql_num_rows($query) != 0) {
        header("location: $url"); // Redirect
        exit; 
    }
    else {
        echo '<div class="bad">Please enter your email address we used for the invite. If you have any questions or problems please email us at <a href="mailto:none@none.com">none@none.com</a></div> ';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if a form was submitted, BEFORE you start doing the verification:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
   ... form was submitted, validate it
}
```

You're running your query only if something was submitted, but checking the database result regardless. So if nothing gets submitted, you STILL check the number of rows returned, which is obviously zero, since you never ran the query in the first place.